# Compton scattering but not quite

Tags: scattering, scattering-cross-section

Is it possible that for a gamma ray, of around $3$ MeV, when scattering off a nucleus of oxygen (which undergoes mostly Compton scattering), does not always eject a loosely bound electron? If so, what is the probability that a Compton electron does not eject from the atom?

Comment: Are you assuming scattering off a nucleus, or off electrons?

Comment: sorry, as I mentioned below, electrons

Comment: The naive Compton billiard model predicts that if the scattering event has a small enough angle, change of energy is minimal. So theoretically there is room for scattering that changes energy too little, and the electron then should not leave. Calculating probabilities of angles (differential cross-section) is possible in QED, and one may estimate from that probability that scattering results in unejected electron.

Comment: So my guess is, the probability should be equal to (something like) the ratio of electron capture at a given electron energy E divided by the Compton scattering cross section of an electron ejected from the orbital with energy E_e?

Comment: ie it should be like the klein nishina formula, with the ratio of the scattering over absorption contributions to the cross section? does this sound reasonable?

Comment: I was thinking rather to take those scattering angles that result in low enough energy change, and integrate the differential cross-section over those angles. But I don't know this topic very well.

Answer (score 0):

So that's not called Compton scattering. Here's a description, from a radiology article:

*Coherent scattering (also known as Rayleigh, unmodified, classical or elastic scattering) is one of three forms of photon interaction which occurs when the energy of the x-ray or gamma photon is small in relation to the ionization energy of the atom. Such low-energy radiation triggers all the electrons in an atom to vibrate at a similar frequency to the incident photon. Thus, the whole atom acts as a unit and recoils when bombarded by a low-energy photon.*

Basically:

How big is a $E=3$ MeV photon?

$$ \lambda = \frac E {\hbar c} = \frac{3\,{\rm MeV}}{197\,{\rm MeV\cdot fm}}
= 0.05\,{\rm fm}$$

Compare with the Bohr radius:

$$ a_0/\lambda = \frac{\hbar^2}{m_e\alpha}\approx 10^6$$

The amplitude for a photon to interact coherently with a charge distribution that has length scales of $10^6\lambda$ is very small.

A similar situation occurs in elastic $ep$ scattering, for which there is copious data. The form-factor (a momentum-transfer dependent factor that modifies the point particle Coulomb scattering cross section) is the Fourier transform of radial charge distribution.

Presumably, coherent $\gamma$ scattering from the electron cloud would be similar. That is, the photon is sensitive to charge density variations on the scale of $\lambda$, and atomic orbitals are smooth on that scale. One would expect the cross section to go as:

$$ \sigma \sim Z\big(\frac{a_0}{\lambda}\big)^2 \sim \frac Z {E^2} $$

(One may need to include a spin-factor, too).

Anyway, you can expect the cross section to be on the order of 1 trillionth the Compton scattering cross section, which is why the radiology article mentions $E_{\gamma} \lt I(Z) $

Comment: Thanks! I apologise, I worded my question completely wrong xD - I want to understand if Compton photon scattering of a photon off an electron in oxygen is not able to always eject the electron and if so, what is the probability that the electron undergoes compton scattering, but it fails to be ejected? I apologise again for the confusion!

Comment: @JEB Why do you expect $\sigma \sim \frac{Z}{E^2}$? Which radiology article are you referring to?